# python: extract integers from mixed list

Tags: python

(python 2.7.8)

I'm trying to make a function to extract integers from a mixed list. Mixed list can be anything but the e.g. I'm going with is:

```
testList = [1, 4.66, 7, "abc", 5, True, 3.2, False, "Hello", 7]
```

I thought this would be simple, and just wrote:

```
def parseIntegers(mixedList):
    newList = [i for i in mixedList if isinstance(i, int)]
    return newList
```

Problem is that the newList this creates has boolean values as well as integers, meaning it gets me:

```
[1, 7, 5, True, False, 7]
```

Why is that? I also used for loop (for i in mixedList: if isinstace.....), but it's essentially the same(?) and has the same problem.

Comment: Use `type(i) == int` instead.

Comment: Be wary of using `type` - this breaks the concept of polymorphism: if someone subclasses `int`, your code will no longer work.

Comment: @Smashery It seems that they don't want to include subclasses in this case.

Comment: Possibly so - but you'd better know what you're doing if you're trying to circumvent the key feature of object-oriented languages (polymorphism). Maybe using `type` *is* the right thing to do. Just be wary is all.

Comment: @Smashery The problem here is that `bool` *is* a subclass of `int` and it is unwanted, so breaking the `isinstance` guideline and using `type` is correct in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is not to use `type`, but to use a chain of `isinstance` calls. The pitfall of using `type` is that someone could subclass `int` in the future, and then your code won't work. Also, since you are using Python 2.x, you need to consider numbers greater than or equal to 2^31: these are not ints. You need to consider the `long` type:

```
def parseIntegers(mixedList):
    return [x for x in testList if (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, long)) and not isinstance(x, bool)]
```

Reason for needing to consider `long`:

```
>>> a = 2 ** 31
>>> isinstance(a, int)
False
```

Comment: a = 2 ** 31
>>> isinstance(a,int)
True

Comment: >>> type(a)
<type 'int'>

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: This was a change between Python 2 and Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: checked in both python 2 and 3. it same

Comment: Okay, that's strange; because neither the documentation, nor my own tests, seem to support that (my code was copied directly from a Python 2.7.8 shell - same version as the OP). Which version of Python 2 are you using?

Comment: `Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 14:44:27)` and `Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)`

Answer (score 3):

as explained by @pts for isinstance, so use `type` like this

```
[ x for x in testList if type(x)==int ]
```

output:

```
[1, 7, 5, 7]
```

use `set` to remove duplication

Answer (score 2):

Apparently bool is a subclass of int:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> isinstance(42, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance('42', int)
False
>>> isinstance(42, bool)
False
>>>
```

Instead of `isinstance(i, int)`, you can use `type(i) is int` or `isinstance(i, int) and not isinstance(i, bool)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
testList = [1, 4.66, 7, "abc", 5, True, 3.2, False, "Hello", 7]
print([x for x in testList if isinstance(x,int) and not isinstance(x,bool)])
[1, 7, 5, 7]
```