# Extract certain integers from string value, of different length, which contains unwanted integers. Pattern or Position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am somewhat of a beginner programmer and am looking for help and an explanation of a problem. I am looking to extract the ID numbers from a string into new column, then fill in missing numbers.

I am working with pandas dataframe and I have the following set of street names, some with an ID number and others missing:

```
*Start station*:
"19th & L St (31224)"
"14th & R St NW (31202)"
"Paul Rd & Pl NW (31602)"
"14th & R St NW"
"19th & L St"
"Paul Rd & Pl NW"

My desired outcome:
*Start station*         *StartStatNum*
"14th & R St NW"        31202
"19th & L St"           31224
"Paul Rd & Pl NW"       31602
"14th & R St NW"        31202
"19th & L St"           31224
"Paul Rd & Pl NW"       31602
```

I am having difficulty after my first step of splitting.
I can split based on position with the following:

```
def Stat_Num(Stat_Num):
    return Stat_Num.split('(')[-1].split(')')[0].strip()

db["StartStatNum"] = pd.DataFrame({'Num':db['Start station'].apply(Stat_Num)})

But this gives:
*Start station*         *StartStatNum*
"19th & L St (31224)"        31202
"14th & R St NW (31202)"     31224
"Paul Rd & Pl NW (31602)"    31602
"14th & R St NW"            "14th & R St NW"
"19th & L St"               "19th & L St"
"Paul Rd & Pl NW"           "Paul Rd & Pl NW"
```

The problem would then arise when I want to find/fill StartStatNum with the station ID numbers that I don't have.

I have been trying to get to know `str.extract, str.contains, re.findall`
and tried the following as a possible stepping stone:

```
db['Start_S2']  = db['Start_Stat_Num'].str.extract(" ((\d+))")
db['Start_S2']  = db['Start station'].str.contains(" ((\d+))")
db['Start_S2']  = db['Start station'].re.findall(" ((\d+))")
```

I have also tried the following this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725535/python-extract-integers-from-mixed-list)

```
def parseIntegers(mixedList):
return [x for x in db['Start station'] if (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, long)) and not isinstance(x, bool)]
```

However when I pass values in, I get a list 'x' with 1 value.
As a bit of a noob, I don't think going the pattern route is best as it will also take in unwanted integers (although I could possibly turn to Nan's as they would be less than 30000 (the lowest value for ID number) 
I also have an idea that it could be something simple that I'm overlooking, but after about 20 straight hours and a lot of searching, I am at a bit of a loss.

Any help would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that worked for me, firstly extract the numbers in the braces:

```
In [71]:

df['start stat num'] = df['Start station'].str.findall(r'\((\d+)\)').str[0]
df
Out[71]:
             Start station start stat num
0      19th & L St (31224)          31224
1   14th & R St NW (31202)          31202
2  Paul Rd & Pl NW (31602)          31602
3           14th & R St NW            NaN
4              19th & L St            NaN
5          Paul Rd & Pl NW            NaN
```

Now remove the number as we don't need it anymore:

```
In [72]:

df['Start station'] = df['Start station'].str.split(' \(').str[0]
df
Out[72]:
     Start station start stat num
0      19th & L St          31224
1   14th & R St NW          31202
2  Paul Rd & Pl NW          31602
3   14th & R St NW            NaN
4      19th & L St            NaN
5  Paul Rd & Pl NW            NaN
```

Now we can fill in the missing station number by calling map on the df with the `NaN` rows removed, and the station name set as the index, this will lookup the station name and return the station number:

```
In [73]:

df['start stat num'] = df['Start station'].map(df.dropna().set_index('Start station')['start stat num'])
df
Out[73]:
     Start station start stat num
0      19th & L St          31224
1   14th & R St NW          31202
2  Paul Rd & Pl NW          31602
3   14th & R St NW          31202
4      19th & L St          31224
5  Paul Rd & Pl NW          31602
```

Comment: Thank you @EdChum, The first 2 I have got to work. Filling in the NaN's is giving me an error : `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. Is this as taking the string as the index it may be slightly different to another with same ID number? Also, if I could check, in the 2nd line `str.split(' \(').str[0]`. I can understand the split on the ')' but what part does the '\' play?. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your first comment, with regards to the split the `\` is needed to escape the braces so what I'm doing is splitting on ' (' so single space open brace

Comment: When I run the 3 section (to fill NaN's) on my dataset I get the `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. So my thinking is that there may be a street of eg. `Paul Rd & Pl NW` : `31202`, but also another row with same street bit slightly different: eg. `paul Rd & Pl Nw` :  `31202`. Would I need to strip out white space and put to lower case the Start station. hope that makes a little better sence. @EdChum

Comment: Yes you'd have to clean and extract the data before calling `map`

Comment: Sorry: In other words, setting 'Start station' as index, there may be same values but spelt slightly different (but having same ID number). Therefore not making them unique

Comment: You'd have to merge in that case something like `df.merge(df.dropna(), on='Start station', how='left')` I think should work

Comment: I have marked as answered, but just for clarity for anyone stumbling upon this question. I had to do something slightly different due to the data. the street names in my data were entered inconsistently. i.e. 'Paul Rd & Pl NW' and 'PI  & Paul Rd NW'. This caused problems with merge and grouping. To overcome this, I was forced to drop some instances and merge with a separate file containing proper station names (merged on station name after cleaning, white space strip, and putting to lower case.) Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to create a dataframe with the transformation

```
station -> id
```

like

```
l = ["19th & L St (31224)",
    "14th & R St NW (31202)",
    "Paul Rd & Pl NW (31602)",
    "14th & R St NW",
    "19th & L St",
    "Paul Rd & Pl NW",]

df = pd.DataFrame( {"station":l})
df_dict = df['station'].str.extract("(?P<station_name>.*)\((?P<id>\d+)\)").dropna()
print df_dict

 # result:
       station_name     id
 0      19th & L St   31224
 1   14th & R St NW   31202
 2  Paul Rd & Pl NW   31602
 [3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Starting from there, you can use some list comprehension:

```
l2 = [ [row["station_name"], row["id"]]
       for line in l
       for k,row in df_dict.iterrows()
       if row["station_name"].strip() in line]
```

to get:

```
 [['19th & L St ', '31224'], 
  ['14th & R St NW ', '31202'], 
  ['Paul Rd & Pl NW ', '31602'], 
  ['14th & R St NW ', '31202'], 
  ['19th & L St ', '31224'], 
  ['Paul Rd & Pl NW ', '31602']]
```

I let you transform the later in dataframe...

There might be nicer solutions for the last part at least...