# How to check type of an element in python list

Tags: python, list

1) I have this list in python.

```
my_list = ['9', 'sam', 'USA', '25']
```

How to get only the numbers from this list? I want to filter only the numbers.

2) And, if I have something like this. How to get only the number? Not using the substrings or whatever. Because the text is dynamic. Is there a way to get only numbers from a text in python?

```
text = "I am 28 years old."`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: extract integers from mixed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725535/python-extract-integers-from-mixed-list)

Comment: Boooo put in a little effort

Comment: also kind of answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float

Comment: You want to filter and get the numbers in floats? Or still in string form?

Comment: I want to get number as an int or a float. Got the answer from this.   my_list = ['9', 'sam', 'USA', '25']
[item for item in my_list if item.isdigit()]  And, generating the list from a string like this. text = "I am 28 years old"   my_list = ['I','am','28','years','old']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
my_list = ['9', 'sam', 'USA', '25']
[item for item in my_list if item.isdigit()]
```

For your second question:

```
import re
re.findall("[0-9]+",text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful list comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in my_list if item.isnumeric()]
['9', '25']
```

**Suggested Readings:**

- [String methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'. isdigit() worked for me. Thanks