# Python get number from mixed list

Tags: python, list

I have following list

```
count =('OK', ['3'])
```

i need to extract number, tried [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725535/python-extract-integers-from-mixed-list)  but only got

```
[]
```

Comment: `number = int(count[1][0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tuple with a list nested inside that contains a string '3' so you can format that however you want.

This is verified by:

```
count =('OK', ['3'])
print(type(count))
for item in count:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        print(item)
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        print(item)
```

resulting in:

```
<class 'tuple'>
['3']
```

To access it as mentioned in comments:

```
number = int(count[1][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count =('OK', ['3','2'])
for item in count :
    if type(item) == list :
        item_in_list = [val for val in item ]
print(item_in_list)
```

OutPut : ['3','2']

This is what I came up with!
You can extract the number in the list if you want and print